# How to connect to VPN using PowerShell native cmdlet

Tags: windows, powershell, vpn, powershell-remoting

Every answer on here is using rasdial. Is there another way to do it? My VPN credentials are already saved so hopefully just the name of the VPN and that's it.
Something like, `Start-VPN -Name "MyVPN"`

I'm not running on a server btw.

Thanks.

Comment: "VPN" describes a _conceptual_ private network. The protocol for establishing a session or connection depends entirely on the implementation. What VPN product are you using?

Comment: I'm using Azure VPN.